Converting an interface to an array tuple type of [ interface key, interface value ][]
I have this interface:
interface SocketServerEvents {
   complete : (data :string)=>void;
   response : (data :number)=>void;
  error : (error:string)=>void;
}

I want to convert it to a type that matches something like this:
[
  [ "complete", (data :string)=>void ],
  [ "response", (data :number)=>void ],
  [ "error", (data :number)=>void ]
]

The point is that the array is an array of tuples where:

Each value is [ keyof SocketServer Events, valueOfThatKey SocketServerEvents ]
Keys can be repeated
Keys are optional

Can this be done in TypeScript?

Does this approach meet your needs? If so I'll write up an answer or find a suitable duplication source; if not, what am I missing?

Honestly, this works great. VSCode is not correctly inferring the anonymous function parameter for me with the itelli-non-sense, but if I type the function incorrectly it will error. So it seems to be working just fine.

The type you're looking for is
type SocketServerEventsEntryArray = Array<
  ["complete", (data: string) => void] | 
  ["response", (data: number) => void] | 
  ["error", (error: string) => void]
>;

You can make TypeScript compute that for you in terms of SocketServerEnvents as follows:
type Entry<T> = { [K in keyof T]: [K, T[K]] }[keyof T];
type EntryArray<T> = Array<Entry<T>>;

The Entry<T> utility type is a distributed object type as coined in microsoft/TypeScript#47109. A distributive object type is a mapped type into which you immediately index to get a union result. A type of the form type G<K extends PropertyKey> = {[P in K]: F<P>}[K] will cause G<K1 | K2 | K3> to distribute over the union in its argument to make F<K1> | F<K2> | F<K3>.  So [K, T[K]] is the tuple you care about for a particular key K, and Entry<T> distributes that over the union of keys in keyof T.  And then we just wrap in Array<T>, which naturally gives you the ability to have repeats or missing elements.
So you can write
type SocketServerEventsEntryArray = EntryArray<SocketServerEvents>;

and you're done.

Note that there's an outstanding bug at microsoft/TypeScript#55632 preventing a discriminated union of tuple types like Entry<SocketServerEvents> from having proper IntelliSense or from contextually inferring the parameter type of the callback.  That means you'll have to work harder to create a value of this type (and that would go away if you changed [K, T[K]] to an object like {k: K, v: T[K]}), but it's still the right type for the question as asked.
Playground link to code
